# How to capture and replace all patterns on a line containing a separate pattern with Regex

Tags: regex, sublimetext3, pcre

I'm trying to set up a regular expression that will allow me to replace 2 spaces with a tab, but only on lines containing a certain pattern.

```
foo: here  is  some  sample  text
bar: here  is  some  sample  text
```

In the above example I want to replace any groups of 2 spaces with a tab, but only on lines that contain "bar":

```
foo: here  is  some  sample  text
bar: here    is    some    sample    text
```

The closest that I've gotten has been using this:

```
Find: ^(\s.*)(bar)(.*)  (.*)
Replace: \1\2\3\t\4
```

However, this only replaces one group of two spaces at a time, so I end up with this:

```
foo: here  is  some  sample  text
bar: here  is  some  sample    text
```

I could execute the replace 3 more times and get my desired result, but I am dealing with text files that may contain hundreds of these sequences.

I am using Sublime Text, but I'm pretty sure that it uses PCRE for its Regex.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works as well

```
(?m-s)(?:^(?=.*\bbar\b)|(?!^)\G).*?\K[ ]{2}
```

https://regex101.com/r/vnM649/1
or
https://regex101.com/r/vnM649/2

Explained

```
 (?m-s)               # Multi-line mode, not Dot-All mode
 (?:
      ^                    # Only test at BOL for 'bar'
      (?= .* \b bar \b )
   |                     # or,
      (?! ^ )              # Not BOL, must have found 2 spaces in this line before
      \G                   # Start where last 2 spaces left off
 )
 .*?                  # Minimal any character (except newline)
 \K                   # Ignore anything that matched up to this point
 [ ]{2}               # 2 spaces to replace with a \t
```

---

`possible to translate this to work with Python?`

Yes.

The `\G` construct gives the ability to do it all 
in a single pass regex. Python `regex` module supports it, 
but not it's `re` module. If using the re module, you need 
to do it in 2 steps.

First is to match the line(s) where `bar` is
then to pass it to a callback to replace all double
spaces to a tabs, then return it as the replacement
back to the caller.

***Sample Python code:***

https://rextester.com/AYM96859

```
 #python 2.7.12

 import re

 def replcall(m):
     contents = m.group(1)
     return re.sub( r'[ ]{2}',"\t", contents )

 str = (
 r'foo: here  is  some  sample  text' + "\n"
 r'bar: here    is    some    sample    text' + "\n"
 )

 newstr = re.sub( r'(?m)(^(?=.*\bbar\b)(?=.*[ ]{2}).*)', replcall, str )

 print newstr
```

The regex to get the line, expanded:

```
 (?m)
 (                             # (1 start)
      ^ 
      (?= .* \b bar \b )
      (?= .* [ ]{2} )
      .* 
 )                             # (1 end)
```

Comment: Please don't vandalize your posts.

Answer (score 0):

This will work:

```
Find: (^(?!.*bar).*)|  
Replace: \1\t
```

(notice the 2 spaces at the end of the "find" regex) but it'll add a tab at the end of the `foo` line.

See [here](https://regex101.com/r/CKOjtV/1) a PCRE demo.